How can I get the android.accounts.Account after successfully sign in with Google
I'm working on Android sign in with Google and hope to get the account's gender and birthday after successfully sign in. I can successfully get the birthday by using GoogleSignIn and People api. However, I notice that GoogleSignIn is deprecated and Credential Manager is recommended. After I successfully sign in by following this document:https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg, the result is GetCredentialResponse. I can get idToken, name, id, etcs from this GetCredentialResponse. But GoogleAccountCredential need to set the Account, which is android.accounts.Account. Anyone know how I can get the account according GetCredentialResponse/idToken? Thanks.
private fun getAdditionalUserInfo(
activity: Activity,
account: GoogleSignInAccount,
) {
    val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
    activity,
    listOf(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read"
    )
  )
   credential.selectedAccount = account.account
   val peopleService = PeopleService.Builder(
     GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
     GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
     credential
   )
   .setApplicationName("Your Application Name")
   .build()

  viewModelScope.launch {
     try {
       val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         peopleService.people().get("people/me")
         .setPersonFields("birthdays,genders")
         .execute()
       }

val birthdays = response?.birthdays
val genders = response?.genders

_isAccountPickerViewVisible.value = false
_googleIdTokenCredential.value =
  "birthday:$birthdays\n" +
  "genders: $genders"
} catch (e: Exception) {
e.printStackTrace()
   }
  }
 }


The Account class has a constructor that takes an email and a type. You can get the email from the GoogleIdTokenCredential (the 'id' field) and for the type, use "com.google", so you can build an account object:
Account account = new Account(googleIdTokenCredential.getId(), "com.google");

As a side note, you can also use the Authorization APIs as well, to get the tokens that you want after the sign-in.

Thank you so much @Ali Naddaf! I have one more question: what does "type" mean when construct the Account instance? Can I still pass "com.google" even for other types accounts? I noticed the post and passed the package as the type, and the code could work as well. Does this mean it doesn't matter what I pass for the "type" parameter?

You are welcome. Your use case was related to Google ID Tokens and Google accounts, so the type "com.google" is the only type that you'd be using for that. In general, there might be other types of accounts on the device; for example, on a Samsung device, Samsung may create a "samsung" type account, or Facebook can create its own type of account.

Hi @Ali Naddaf, I have another questyion: can Credential Manager display a login options dialog that lists all available sign-in options, including Google accounts, Microsoft accounts, as well as accounts stored by Autofill and passkeys? Is there a way to implement this? According to the official document, Credential Manager supports multiple sign-in methods such as passkey, username and password, and autofill.  Can Credential Manager get Microsoft accounts and list all of the available credentials in one login options dialog? Thanks
